# JavaScript regex pattern for any visible unicode letter characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a JavaScript application that requires me to identify the set of "any visible Unicode letter characters, digits (0-9), spaces, underscores, and periods". The suggested regex pattern is `^[0-9\\p{L} _\\.]+$`, but that doesn't seem to work in JavaScript. The part that is giving me trouble is "any visible Unicode letter characters" because that includes non-English characters. Is there some JavaScript regex pattern that can identify the Unicode letter character set?

Comment: Your pattern is valid in XRegExp.

Comment: What is "any visible Unicode letter characters"? All Unicode letters? See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jqyu47qo/).

Comment: Thanks guys, the demo looks like XRegExp will do the trick. If you're curious I'm trying to validate summoner names for a League of Legends website. This is the full set of characters that they define as  "any visible Unicode letter characters, digits (0-9), spaces, underscores, and periods" https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/201752814-Summoner-Name-FAQ#h1q5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `XRegExp` library to parse your current regular expression:

```js
var pattern = new XRegExp("^[0-9\\p{L} _.]+$");
var s = "123 Московская Street.";
if (XRegExp.test(s, pattern)) {
    console.log("Valid");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.2.0/xregexp-all.min.js"></script>
```

Note that `^[0-9\\p{L} _\\.]+$` matches

- `^`  - start of string
- `[0-9\\p{L} _\\.]+` - one or more chars tha are:

  - `0-9` - ASCII digits
  - `\\p{L}` - letters
  - - space
  - `_` - an underscore
  - `.` - a dot (inside a character class, `.` matches a literal dot, no need to escape)
- `$` - end of string.

If you want to also include the following conditions:

- Names must be at least 3 characters long and no more than 16 characters long.
- No player name can include the word "Riot" in it.

You may extend the pattern to the following:

```
var pattern = new XRegExp("^(?!.*\\bRiot\\b)[0-9\\p{L} _\\.]{3,16}$");
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                ^^^^^^
```

where `+` (1 or more occurrences) is replaced with `{3,16}` limiting quantifier (3 to 16 occurrences) and `(?!.*\\bRiot\\b)` negative lookahead will fail the match if there is a whole word (due to `\\b` word boundaries) `Riot` is anywhere inside the string (or line, since `.` matches any char but line break chars).