# Regex to match both English and Russian beginnings and ends of sentences

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex below detects sentences in a string:

`str.match(/[A-Z][^\.!\?]*[\.!\?]+/g);`

but it only works with English letters. I want it to also detect Russian sentences and (just in case) sentences that start with letters in other languages, such as the French Ç and the German Ä (as well as the Swedish Å etc.

What would be the *ultimate* Regex to split a string into sentences that works for other languages, not only for English?

I tried

`str.match(/[A-Z][А-Я][^\.!\?]*[\.!\?]+/g);`

or also this

`str.match(/^.*?[.!?](?:\s|$)(?!.*\))/gm)`

but it doesn't work...

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45886840/4934172).

Answer (score 1):

[ECMAScript (2018) supports Unicode Property Value Expressions natively](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#prod-UnicodePropertyValueExpression).

You can match a single character belonging to the "letter" category with `\p{L}`. You can match a single character not belonging to that category with `\P{L}`.

```
str.match(/\\p{L}[^\.!\?]*[\.!\?]+/g);
```

Given this capability there are a huge number of UPVE options:

```
\p{L}  or \p{Letter}: any kind of letter from any language.
\p{Ll} or \p{Lowercase_Letter}: a lowercase letter that has an uppercase variant.
\p{Lu} or \p{Uppercase_Letter}: an uppercase letter that has a lowercase variant.
\p{Lt} or \p{Titlecase_Letter}: a letter that appears at the start of a word when only the first letter of the word is capitalized.
\p{L&} or \p{Cased_Letter}: a letter that exists in lowercase and uppercase variants (combination of Ll, Lu and Lt).
\p{Lm} or \p{Modifier_Letter}: a special character that is used like a letter.
\p{Lo} or \p{Other_Letter}: a letter or ideograph that does not have lowercase and uppercase variants.
\p{M}  or \p{Mark}: a character intended to be combined with another character (e.g. accents, umlauts, enclosing boxes, etc.).
\p{Mn} or \p{Non_Spacing_Mark}: a character intended to be combined with another character without taking up extra space (e.g. accents, umlauts, etc.).
\p{Mc} or \p{Spacing_Combining_Mark}: a character intended to be combined with another character that takes up extra space (vowel signs in many Eastern languages).
\p{Me} or \p{Enclosing_Mark}: a character that encloses the character is is combined with (circle, square, keycap, etc.).
\p{Z}  or \p{Separator}: any kind of whitespace or invisible separator.
\p{Zs} or \p{Space_Separator}: a whitespace character that is invisible, but does take up space.
\p{Zl} or \p{Line_Separator}: line separator character U+2028.
\p{Zp} or \p{Paragraph_Separator}: paragraph separator character U+2029.
\p{S}  or \p{Symbol}: math symbols, currency signs, dingbats, box-drawing characters, etc.
\p{Sm} or \p{Math_Symbol}: any mathematical symbol.
\p{Sc} or \p{Currency_Symbol}: any currency sign.
\p{Sk} or \p{Modifier_Symbol}: a combining character (mark) as a full character on its own.
\p{So} or \p{Other_Symbol}: various symbols that are not math symbols, currency signs, or combining characters.
\p{N}  or \p{Number}: any kind of numeric character in any script.
\p{Nd} or \p{Decimal_Digit_Number}: a digit zero through nine in any script except ideographic scripts.
\p{Nl} or \p{Letter_Number}: a number that looks like a letter, such as a Roman numeral.
\p{No} or \p{Other_Number}: a superscript or subscript digit, or a number that is not a digit 0–9 (excluding numbers from ideographic scripts).
\p{P}  or \p{Punctuation}: any kind of punctuation character.
\p{Pd} or \p{Dash_Punctuation}: any kind of hyphen or dash.
\p{Ps} or \p{Open_Punctuation}: any kind of opening bracket.
\p{Pe} or \p{Close_Punctuation}: any kind of closing bracket.
\p{Pi} or \p{Initial_Punctuation}: any kind of opening quote.
\p{Pf} or \p{Final_Punctuation}: any kind of closing quote.
\p{Pc} or \p{Connector_Punctuation}: a punctuation character such as an underscore that connects words.
\p{Po} or \p{Other_Punctuation}: any kind of punctuation character that is not a dash, bracket, quote or connector.
\p{C}  or \p{Other}: invisible control characters and unused code points.
\p{Cc} or \p{Control}: an ASCII or Latin-1 control character: 0x00–0x1F and 0x7F–0x9F.
\p{Cf} or \p{Format}: invisible formatting indicator.
\p{Co} or \p{Private_Use}: any code point reserved for private use.
\p{Cs} or \p{Surrogate}: one half of a surrogate pair in UTF-16 encoding.
\p{Cn} or \p{Unassigned}: any code point to which no character has been assigned.
```

↳ [21.2.2.12 Character Class Escape | ECMAScript 2018](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#prod-CharacterClassEscape)